# Why do I lose the current object state when 'this.props.actions.updateComment(event.target.value)' is called?

Tags: javascript, redux, reactjs

I trying trying to achieve the following: There is a textfield and once a user enters in a text, an object is created with the text assigned to a state property called 'commentText' which is located inside the 'comments' array which is inside the object (todo[0]) of 'todos' array. 'commentInput' is just a temporary storage for the input entered in the textfield, to be assigned to the 'commentText' of 'todo[0]' object's 'comments' array.

I retrieve the current state object via following:

```
const mapStateToProps=(state, ownProps)=>({
  todo:state.todos.filter(todo=>todo.id==ownProps.params.id)
});
```

and dispatch and actions via:

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return{
actions: bindActionCreators(actions, dispatch)
}
```

So the retrieved object 'todo' has an array property named comments. I have a text field that has:

```
onChange={this.handleCommentChange.bind(this)}
```

which does:

```
  handleCommentChange(event){
    this.props.actions.updateComment(event.target.value)
  }
```

Before handleCommentChange is called, the object 'todo[0]' is first fetched correctly:

[image]

But as soon as a text is inputted into the text field, onChange={this.handleCommentChange.bind(this)} is called and all of a sudden, 'todo[0]' state is all lost (as shown in the 'next state' log):

[image]

What may be the issue? Tried solving it for hours and hours but still stuck. Any guidance or insight would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

EDIT **:

```
  {
    this.props.newCommentsArray.map((comment) => {
      return <Comment key={comment.id} comment={comment} actions={this.props.actions}/>
    })
  }
```

EDIT 2 **

```
case 'ADD_COMMENT':
  return todos.map(function(todo){
//Find the current object to apply the action to
    if(todo.id === action.id){
//Create a new array, with newly assigned object
      return var newComments = todo.comments.concat({
        id: action.id,
        commentTxt: action.commentTxt  
      })
    }
    //Otherwise return the original array
    return todo.comments 
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that your reducer is not correctly updating the todo entry.  It's probably replacing the contents of the entry entirely, rather than merging the incoming value in in some fashion.

edit:

Yup, after seeing your full code, your reducer is very much at fault.  Here's the current code:

```
case 'ADD_COMMENT':
  return todos.map(function(todo){
    if(todo.id === action.id){
      return todo.comments = [{
        id: action.id,
        commentTxt: action.commentTxt
      }, ...todo.comments]
    }
  })
```

`map()` should be returning one item for every item in the array.  Instead, you're *only* returning something if the ID matches, and even then, you're actually *assigning* to `todo.comments` (causing direct mutation) and returning the result of that statement (which might be `undefined`?).

You need something like this instead (which could be written shorter, but I've deliberately written it out long-form to clarify what's happening):

```
case 'ADD_COMMENT':
    return todos.map(function(todo) {
        if(todo.id !== action.id) {
            // if the ID doesn't match, just return the existing objecct
            return todo;
        }

        // Otherwise, we need to return an updated value:

        // Create a new comments array with the new comment at the end.  concat() will
        // You could also do something like [newComment].concat(todo.comments) to produce 
        // a new array with the new comment first depending on how you want it ordered.
        var newComments = todo.comments.concat({
            id : action.id,
            commentTxt : action.commentTxt
        });

        // Create a new todo object that is a copy of the original, 
        // but with a new value in the "comments" field
        var newTodo = Object.assign({}, todo, {comments : newComments});

        // Now return that instead
        return newTodo;
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. Is there a way to log it or view if it is being updated properly?

Comment: I have a number of Redux debug and development tools listed at https://github.com/markerikson/redux-ecosystem-links/blob/master/devtools.md that might be useful.  Beyond that, it might help if you could post the code for your reducer.

Comment: Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/jaewonch/0c52907c06fea42503c5f62bcfbbb56d and I provided a comment underneath for more clarification. Thank you!

Comment: Updated now that I definitely see the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the insight! Will definitely give it a try but after a brief look, I was wondering if it's possible to directly edit the state (commentTxt) defined initially (under ADD_TODO) in the 'comments' array.

Comment: You _don't_ want to "directly edit" anything.  That's the point - Redux wants you to always do _immutable_ updates.  That means always making copies and modifying the copies, never modifying the original values.  See http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#react-not-rerendering and https://github.com/markerikson/react-redux-links/blob/master/immutable-data.md for more information on this topic.

Comment: what's the reason for Object.assign? Hasn't the new object been already created with the new information, and added to todo.comments array, and newly assigned to newComments array?

Comment: I made an EDIT** in the original post for more clarification. I would like to retrieve back the 'comments' array and whenever, new comment is added to the 'comments' array, would like to render the <Comment/> component. So in that case, how can I access the newly updated comments array (confused at returning two different data, newTodo and todo)? At the moment in the example, I just defined it as 'this.props.newCommentsArray' .

Comment: Made a new EDIT 2**. Would something like that work?

Comment: Your Edit #2 is wrong.  You're mixing up trying to return a _todo item_, vs updating the _comments within an item_.  With `map`, you always need to return one item for every item in the original array.  For this case, you want to either return the original items (for all items other than the one you're "updating"), or return an entirely new object for the one you're updating.  So, you need to create a new Comment object, create a new comments array containing that Comment object, and then create a new Todo object containing the new array.

Comment: Sorry but could you show with another example? I've been trying but still stuck. Don't think I understand it correctly.

Comment: Just checking to see if you've seen it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The example I wrote should be sufficient.  If you're having trouble understanding it, I suggest you go read the articles on immutable data at the link I posted to better understand the concepts.

Comment: Sure thing! Just one quick clarification, how would you retrieve the data returned from 'ADD_COMMENT'? Because it returns two different objects depending on the case, todo or newTodo.

Comment: Note that the code I wrote is for your _reducer_.  The result of that case statement is a new array, containing _almost_ all the same items as the original, but with a new todo item replacing the old todo item, and the new todo item containing an updated comments array.  Your component should still access the data the same way it was before, retrieving the list of todos from the store and rendering them.

Comment: Got it, but isn't it returning a new object, rather than an array with newly updated state? return todo and newTodo are each supposed to represent an object.

Comment: _Please_ read the code carefully.  the `map()` function returns a new array overall.  Within that, the callback either returns the old Todo item untouched (the ones we aren't updating), or makes an updated copy of the one we _do_ want to update and returns the updated copy.  The end result is a new array that has almost all of the old items, but with a new updated Todo swapped in, and that new array is returned as the new overall state.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification! Finally got it down and implemented it. The first comment got added properly but once the second comment has been added, I got the following error: flattenChildren(...): Encountered two children with the same key, `1:$0`. Child keys must be unique; when two children share a key, only the first child will be used.

Comment: When rendering an array of items in React, each item should have a unique key so React can tell them apart during later updates.  If the IDs in your comments aren't unique, that will cause a problem.  Check how you're defining the ID field in the "add comment "action creator.